# Can we get the log of two sides of an inequation without modifying the symbol?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

This might sound retarded for your standards.

But the higher x gets, the higher $\log_{10}(x)$ gets, right?

Does the same principle apply for $\log_{2}(x)$ ?

And by that matter if I have the following expression:

$$n! \leq n^n$$ 
Does $\leq $ hold?

$$\log_{2}(n!) \leq \log_{2}(n^n)$$

Comment: Yes, log to any base $\gt 1$ is an increasing function, so if $0\lt x\lt y$ then $\log_2 x \lt \log_2 y$.

Comment: Your logic is correct!  For $n!\leq n^n$, just notice that the left has $n$ terms ALL of which are less than or equal to n, but the right hand side has $n$ terms all equal to $n$. And no question is ever retarded. If the question shows thought, like yours does, its the best kind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah the logarithm is a strict monotone increasing function, so if 
$$a\leq b \implies \log(a) \leq \log(b)$$
This is true for the natural logarithm and hence for all logarithm with base greater 1.

The derivative of the logarithm is $\frac{1}{x}$ and hence for $x>0$ always positive. So in fact if $a,b$ are strictly greater zero you get 
$$ a\leq b \iff \log (a) \leq \log(b)$$

To see it is monotone you just can use logarithm laws and the fact that $\log(x)>0$ whenever $x>1$. So  you have 
$$\log(a)=\log\left(b\cdot \frac{a}{b}\right)=\log(b)+\log\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$$
so if $\frac{a}{b}>1$ you add something positive else you add something negative.

Answer (score 1):

This is true if the base of the log is larger than $1$.

Think of it this way. If $a > b$ then $\frac{a}{b} > 1$. Now we have reduced it to a single special case (proved below). Applying the log to both sides gives $\log_c \left( \frac{a}{b} \right) > 0$. This simplifies to $\log_c a - \log_c b > 0$, and so $\log_c a > \log_c b$.

To prove the special case, use whatever definition of logarithm works best, and show that $x > 1 \implies \ln x > 0$. (A comprehensive answer here is hard due to the multiple definitions that people choose for logs and exponentials). This shows that $\log_c x = \frac{ \ln x }{ \ln c } > 0$.